# Calcular centro más cercano algoritmo k-medias

Tags: python, inteligencia-artificial

"calcula_centro_mas_cercano(dato,centros,distancia)" que recibiendo como entrada un dato, una lista de centros de cada cluster y una función distancia, devuelve el número de cluster cuyo centro está más cercano al dato (los clusters los numeraremos de 0 a K-1).

He hecho esto pero no está bien:

```
def calcula_centro_mas_cercano(dato,centros,distancia):
x=0;
for centro in centros:
    distancia = distancia_abs(centro[0],dato)
    if centro <= distancia:
        x = 0;
    else:
        x=1;
return x;
```

Tengo definida una funcion distancia_abs(x,y):

```
def distancia_abs(x,y):
return abs(x[0]-y[0])
```

¿Cómo podría mejorarlo?

Comment: ¿Usando el teorema de pitágoras?

Comment: No , con la distancia en valor absoluto

Comment: Pues eso, el teorema de Pitágoras te da la distancia en valor absoluto entre dos puntos,.Siendo los catetos la la diferencia de coordenadas x e y respectivamente, la hipotenusa es la distancia buscada.